# Why should we use a pointer to store an address in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I was learning C language where I saw that pointers are variables that store the address of other variables. So I ran this code:

```
int x = 10;
int *p;
p = &x;
printf("%i\n", p);
```

> Result: 6422292

Then I tried to do the same thing without using pointers, just using a variable to store the address:

```
 int z = 10;
 int v;
 v = &z;
 printf("%i", v);
```

> Result: 6422282

Since we can use variables to store other variables' address, why do we use pointers at all?

Comment: You probably got a boatload of compiler warnings. Start there. Study the warnings.

Comment: `%i`  specifes that the argumet is an integer, not a pointer to an integer. Try it with `printf("%i", *p);`. A pointer just points to a value, but its own value *is* a memory address. And that address is where the actual value pointed to resides in memory. To get to the value via a pointer, you dereference it by prefixing it with `*`.
Also,do not use an integer to store an address. Addresses have different sizes depending on architecture.

Comment: Because pointers are the type used to store addresses.  The fact that a regular `int` works in your environment is a coincidence'.  I'd also guess that `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(int*)` are different in your environment (assuming you're on a 64-bit environment).

Comment: In the first snippet, where you are printing a pointer, it should be `printf("%p\n", (void*)p);` This gives you the address that is being stored by the pointer variable.

Comment: How would you dereference `v` in the 2nd snippet, without using a pointer type `int*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers are not integers.  They *may* have integral representation, but they do not behave like integers and should not be treated like integers.  Note that on platforms like `x86_64` an `int` is not wide enough to store a pointer value.

Pointers are a distinct class of datatypes for storing the location of an object or function - they are an *abstraction* of a memory address, with additional type information.  Remember, a data type isn't just about what values you can store, but also about what operations you can perform on those values.  Pointer operations are distinct from integer operations.  The `+` and `-` operators mean very different things for integer and pointer types.  The unary `*` operator is not defined for integer types.  The arithmetic `*` and `/` operators are not defined for pointer types. 
 And so on.

Pointers to different types are themselves different types and are not interchangeable.  Pointer arithmetic (the basis of array subscripting) is based on the pointed-to type.  That is, if `cp` is a `char *` pointing to a `char` object, then `cp + 1` yields the location of the *next `char` object* immediately following.  If `ip` is an `int *` pointing to an `int` object, then `ip + 1` yields the location of the *next `int` object* immediately following:

```
   +---+
c: |   | <--- cp
   +---+
   |   | <--- cp + 1
   +---+
    ...
   +---+
i: |   | <--- ip
   +---+
   |   |
   +---+
   |   |
   +---+
   |   |
   +---+
   |   | <-- ip + 1
   +---+
   |   |
   +---+
   |   |
   +---+
   |   |
   +---+
    ...
```

This is what I mean about pointers not *behaving* like integers.  They have their own distinct semantics.

C expects the operand of the unary `*` operator to have pointer type.  If you try to deference an integer, even if that integer object stores a valid address value, the compiler will yell at you.

Comment: Thanks alot , you made my day . Thanks Buddy .

Answer (score -1):

In case of integer, it looks like good, because address is itself integer, but try to do this with other data type like string , array and any struct . You will get  the idea why we need pointer in C.